# Niece doesn't share any matches from my paternal side?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, half-siblings

My Sister's daughter took a DNA test on Ancestry and matched with me at 1153 CM's 38 Segments at 90cm being the longest. She does not match any of my paternal matches. every match we have in common, comes from my mother's family. Does this mean that her mother and I have different fathers?

Answer (score 1):

She is a half-niece.  Her mother and I do not share the same bio-dad. She sent me all the matches on her end, that I did not share in common with her, and they are all for my supposed paternal line. I just don't have any of those same matches on my side.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at the [The Shared cM Project 4.0 tool v4 for 1,153cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1153) the chances of her being a half-niece appears very high and:

> falls outside the bounds of the recorded cM range (99th percentile)

for a full one.